# UIButton shadow on all 4 sides

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, ios8, shadow

I am trying to generate shadow for a UIButton.

Below is what I am using.

```
myButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
myButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
myButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
myButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(4, 4);
myButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

But its generating shadow on right and bottom.

Is there way where I can have shadow on all 4 sides?

As an another solution, I am do this by putting image with shadow behind the button, but I don't want to go that way.

Is there any way to get this done programmatically?

Something like below.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you offset the shadow by `{4, 4}` the shadow appears on the bottom-right side of the button. You could set a zero offset :

```
myButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
```

and by tweaking the `shadowRadius` you might achieve what you want.

Here is how a shadow is built:

(1st row) start from your button's shape

(2nd row) draw a black shape underneath your button and translate it by the amount specified in `shadowOffset` : 10px on the left, 0px on the right. On the right one you can't see the black rectangle as it's directly underneath the button

(3rd row) blur the black rectangle by the amount specified in `blurRadius`. Zero means no blur and the black rectangle would stay sharp, so if you don't offset and don't blur, you'll see nothing.

[image]

Comment: I believe  CGSizeZero is equivalent to CGSizeMake(0,0), which means there won't be any shadow... right?

Comment: No, it means the shadow won't be offset, it'll be centered on the button. If you provide a radius greater than zero, the shadow will bleed equally on all sides of the button.

Comment: still not coming.. I have layer.shadowRadius = 0; & layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;

Comment: Provide a radius of 8 instead of zero. If you don't blur (radius=0) and don't offset the shadow, you won't see anything. I'll update my answer to show you how it works.

Comment: self.ResetNo.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0; set radius like this but its not look like you last image.answer please & thanks